# error Migrations are pending; run 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to rollback the last migration :

```
rake db:rollback
```

it show  me the following :

```
==  AddUserIdToPictures: reverting ============================================
-- remove_index(:pictures, {:column=>[:user_id, :visible]})
-> 0.1201s
-- remove_column(:pictures, :user_id, :integer)
-> 0.0127s
==  AddUserIdToPictures: reverted (0.1567s) ===================================
```

then if i try to access some page i get error :

```
Migrations are pending; run 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue
```

but when i do what error says : rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development , it recreate what i rollback above :

```
==  AddUserIdToPictures: migrating ============================================
-- add_column(:pictures, :user_id, :integer)
-> 0.0300s
-- add_index(:pictures, [:user_id, :visible])
-> 0.1007s
==  AddUserIdToPictures: migrated (0.1310s) ===================================
```

what is wrong here ? should i remove the migration file before i run the command ?

Comment: thats it, if its present it assumes it should be run

Comment: what about if i run rake db:rollback for the second time after removing this migration file , it will rollback the last migration file existing right ?

Comment: it works fine now thank you, i run rollback for another migration which create my 'pictures' table but this time not shows me the error of need to run rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development, i don't know why this error is specific to creating column and index (but not table)

Comment: @apneadiving i also did a lot of rollback in the past, but never removed any migration file, this will be dangerous ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you rollback a migration, the database schema is reverted to the previous migration.

However, if you leave the migration inside the migrations folder, Rails assumes the migration should be run and will not working until you migrate to the most recent schema.

If you want to rollback the schema you should discard the migration. Delete the file and Rails will not complain.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Rails creates a schema_migrations table, composed of a single column named 'version' containing the most recent schema migration id string. The id string corresponds to the id string in db/schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140284052547) do

  # Your model definitions

end
```

If the version string in SchemaMigration#version doesn't match what is in db/schema.rb, you will get the 'Migrations are pending' exception. This sometimes happens if you setup a new system or do a clean OS install and then restore the database from a backup file, along with running 'rake db:migrate' - the version strings will get out of sync. The way to fix the problem is to simply insert a new row into the schema_migrations table, with the value contained in db/schema.rb - but only do this if you are certain the actual database matches the schema definition in schema.rb:

```
insert into schema_migrations (version) values ('20140284052547');
```

Answer (score 0):

try to rollback 2 last migrations by: 
rake db:rollback STEP=2

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to rollback, instead of

```
rake db:rollback
```

use if you want change in migration file:

```
rake db:migrate:redo STEP=1
```

use it if you want to drop table

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=your_migration_version
```