# Devise Ruby Gem keeps bringing me to sign in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Devise was working great. My app starting telling me I had pending migrations so I had to rollback the db one version. I think that was the only change, but now Devise stopped working. When I sign in, the page refreshes and I'm back at the sign-in page with no notification.

**What does it tell me that resetting back to old working version of my git doesn't fix the issue? I rolled back to 3 or 4 versions I know worked fine, and I still have the same issue. Is there something I should have done differently in my version control? I thought that was whole point.**

My application controller includes:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

So the sign in appears when you launch the application, but after authenticating the index page should load.

The other issue I notice is the signup page no longer sends an email for account verification, which also was working fine. The sign up form after submit brings me right the the sign in form without any notification.

The last thing I notice is that the sign in page no longer has the color formatting to match my css like it did.

Digging into the runtime I've discovered that I'm getting a 401 error both when I submit the password reset and when I try to sign in.

Here:

```
Started PUT "/users/password" for 67.190.148.56 at 2016-03-01 04:48:12 +0000
Cannot render console from 67.190.148.56! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SG2j03FdEJi2OcLZkKet0mR3OllWPbq+ryaIJvxC2YZDYPRhM4SqU3kBuI3Ib4W786ALKB6QvS7/jXzBOMhagQ==", "user"=>{"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Change my password"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["reset_password_token", "28df3becae959de20a18d1b1475cfefa23ad4baa59771dfa0bcf01798531b292"]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "encrypted_password" = ?, "reset_password_token" = ?, "reset_password_sent_at" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$ywUTc3pDw3rY0U6aHR.dZ.BKdP/vcQ7hxNhSgCZlD4LM2e.11efdG"], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["updated_at", "2016-03-01 04:48:12.426544"], ["id", 1]]
   (12.4ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 121ms (ActiveRecord: 13.6ms)
```

Comment: The issue I see in the runtime is that I'm getting an "Unauthorized 401" both when I submit the password reset and when I try to  sign in.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this should give you the answer 
[error Migrations are pending; run 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105711/error-migrations-are-pending-run-rake-dbmigrate-rails-env-development-to-res)

Try this command to rollback, instead of

rake db:rollback
use if you want change in migration file:

rake db:migrate:redo STEP=1
use it if you want to drop table

rake db:migrate:down VERSION=your_migration_version

Comment: I battled this with your suggestion and others for quite a while the other day. The app loaded after the rollback, and if I take away the forced login for devise then the app loads and everything functions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

define an action to configure parameters you want to permitted

application_controller.rb:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters if: :devise_controller?
before_action :authenticate_user!

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) {|u| u.permit(:email)}
end
```

Comment: Thanks Flying Onion. This did not change the behavior at all. Still the same 401 during runtime.

Comment: Have you got the problem settled? Maybe your parameters are not correctly permitted in the devise controller. Could you show the login page view?